# local path generated before hyperlink and page not found error the code <a href=“https://delicious.com/jodi.reed/browsers”> link </a>

Tags: html

I’m just trying to insert an html absolute link to my texteditor on Mac and I get this on the browser url:

```
file:///Users/yasser/Desktop/211Website/Labs/https://delicious.com/jodi.reed/browsers...
```

and file not found in Firefox or Chrome or Safari. When I delete the path before the http the page opens fine...

The code is below-

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <!-- Lab2 Yasser Abdelhalim --> 
    <head> <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
        <title> Lab2 Yasser Abdelhalim </title> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <h1> Yasser’s Web Development resources </h1> this is description for heading number one 
        <div> 
            <h2> Background </h2> 
            <ul> 
                <li><a href=“delicious.com/jodi.reed/browsers”>link</a></li>
                <li><a href=“delicious.com/jodi.reed/browsers”>link</a></li> 
                <li><a href=“delicious.com/jodi.reed/browsers”>link</a></li>
            </ul> 
            <h2> Web programing </h2> 
            <ul>
        </div>
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, what are you trying to do? You're trying to link to a page on your Mac?

Comment: im just writing an html document that it has external links that dont work and open that way.

Comment: Well, are you using builtin Apache or MAMP? Can you paste the page code that contains the link?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<!-- Lab2 Yasser Abdelhalim -->

<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8">

<title> Lab2 Yasser Abdelhalim  </title>

</head>

<body> 

<h1> Yasser’s Web Development resources </h1>

this is description for heading number one

<div>

<h2> Background  </h2>

<ul>

<li>      <a href=“https://delicious.com/jodi.reed/browsers”> link</a> </li>

<li>       <a href=“https://delicious.com/jodi.reed/browsers”> link</a>   </li>

<li>        <a href=“https://delicious.com/jodi.reed/browsers”> link</a>   </li>

</ul>

<h2> Web programing  </h2>

<ul>

</div>

</body>

</html>

Comment: this is the link inside my html page if that what you mean, when i open the link in any browser it says page not found, i dont know what Apache or MAMP even means. way backward i know this is my second week in that basic html course. thx

Comment: page not found and i got this in the url..file:///Users/yasser/Desktop/211Website/Labs/https://delicious.com/jodi.reed/browsers.

Comment: okay, so you need to add http:// to the start of the link for a start. (and you should have added that code to your existing answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think (without seeing anything else) you just need to add the initial part of your URLs, as your ocmputer is thinking they're local, relative files (in the same directory as the file with this code in).

Try using this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> <!-- Lab2 Yasser Abdelhalim -->
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Lab2 Yasser Abdelhalim</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Yasser’s Web Development resources</h1> this is description for heading number one 
    <div>
        <h2>Background</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="https://delicious.com/jodi.reed/browsers">link</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="https://delicious.com/jodi.reed/browsers">link</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="https://delicious.com/jodi.reed/browsers">link</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Try typing the full address in here, including speech marks (double quotes).. sometimes when copying and pasting URLs it copies the formatted speech marks from some fontstyles.

Apache is the webserver that runs on Linux, it pretty much is a foundation or base of every website around (with some exceptions).

Are you using Windows or Mac? You would be better to be working in a proper web server environment (I can explain)

Comment: yours worked , mine didn't .i used to copy and paste the url. http was there but when i added it to comments it omits the https for some reason, I'm trying to see what else you did different its identical but its not. lol very strange , I'm using mac , i would like to thank you so much though

Comment: Firstly, don't copy and paste because I think maybe the double quotes weren't being added correctly. Try typing the address including double quotes. Or move the HTML document to your Sites folder in your user account, and make sure in System Preferences > Sharing that Web Sharing is turned on.

Comment: i think the web share nailed the problem i cant thank you enough , although apple removed the share in the preference, there was a way around that im working on.cheers.

Comment: not resolved , i typed it by hand same thing i can't go with http://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-enable-web-sharing-in-os-x-mountain-lion/ its very complicated.

Comment: Install MAMP, it's a free graphical tool that sets up your mac as a web server

Comment: thanks i will try the problem solved by taking the quotes around the link off.

Comment: Hang on, I don't think taking the quotes will fix it.. You want the quotes there. Can you actually post the code that you're using that's generating the links? Not the output.. but the code?

Comment: i edited five pages all has the quotes and non of had worked,  i went to each link and try it with or without the quotes, all that has quotes didn't work , today i still have no quotes and they all work and validated with no problem. i wish i can know why.but I'm happy they work.

Comment: Fair enough, do you mind accepting my answer and we can close this question? :)

Comment: You need straight quotes instead of typographer quotes. That's what Lee is trying to say.

Comment: Yes! :) like non-formatted quotes that you can get as a result of copying and pasting

Comment: @Yasser As per the HTML5 specification http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#attributes-0 it **is** valid - provided it does not contain one of the invalid characters (basically space, double or single quote, equals or angle brackets. It is however strongly recommended that you always quote attribute values, except boolean attributes which contain no value, to avoid being caught out by one of those cases - in particular space which is commonly used in attribute values. Single or double quotes do not matter, but they must match and be the UTF character codes listed in the specification.

Comment: Or in more layman's terms - quoting attribute values is optional, providing the value doesn't contain whitespace or another invalid character. The quotes must be standard quotes, as cited by Lee and Aibrean.

Comment: thanks guys , fair enough i will continue pushing them in any case possible if they won't miss direct the link, and i have to admit i like the layman thing. cheers.